# Connecting presence point to nearest raster (brick)

Tags: r, maxent

I am currently trying to run the maxent modelling in R on a dataset of moon jellyfish in the north east Atlantic waters. I have environmental variables datasets from Copernicus ocean monitoring service. Since the majority of my presence points have a basis in citizen science observations, they are mostly in coastal areas. My problem is that the environmental variables doesn’t always reach all the way inwards to the coast, and especially fjords and bay areas.  There is a degree of discrepancy between presence points(lat/lon in df) and environmental data(raster (brick)), and due to this some of my analyses give the error: “more than half of the presence points have NA predictor values”.
What I wonder is if there is any way to join these presence points that fall outside to the closest raster?

I have tried a few commands like `st_nearest_feature`, `approxNA` and `focal` but unfortunately none of these seem valid.  Google haven't really led me to any solution either. I have also tried to post my problem in stackoverflow, but received no answer there.

[image: as you can see in this figure some of my presence points (red +) are not covered by rasters]

Comment: I guess you mean "the nearest non-missing (NA) cell of a given raster"?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I added a figure to illustrate:) some presence points falls outside the raster grid

Comment: Are the NA values in the same place over all layers in your stack? If they are then a slight modification of my code will get you the answer. If the NAs are in different places in each layer then you have to apply my code over each layer independently. You can do this is the NAs are in the same place, but there's an optimisation possible if NAs are in the same location across layers.

Comment: yes, they are consistently in the same place trough all layers

Answer (score 2):

Strategy: convert the raster to a set of x,y,value points at the non-NA locations and use a fast nearest neighbour match to get the nearest raster cell value.

Example data: a 10x10 raster of values from 0 to 1, but with NAs in most of it. 50 random points:

```
library(raster) # could be modded to work with terra..
r = raster(outer(1:10,1:10))/100
r[r<0.4] = NA
plot(r)
pts = cbind(runif(50),runif(50))
points(pts)
```

[image]

Function: this takes a set of x,y points and a raster and finds the value in the nearest cell to each point:

```
library(FNN)
nearestValue <- function(pts, r){
    rxy = rasterToPoints(r)
    ind = FNN::knnx.index(rxy[,c("x","y")], pts, 1)[,1]
    rxy[ind, 3]
}
```

Test: plot points by extracted value size:

```
nval = nearestValue(pts, r)
plot(r)
points(pts, cex=nval*2)
```

[image]

which looks right - all the points in the NA zone have values around 0.42 which is the smallest cell on the edge of the non-NA circle. Points in the non-NA area seem to have the values from the raster.

This also works for points outside the raster bounds. Here's another test image result (note also large value pixel in top-left corner of raster):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer! Im sorry though, I forgot to add that i have a raster brick, with 7 layers. so my results when trying this out was kind of weird, also it looks like all values was turned to NA value in my df. 
See figure in next comment

Comment: So either work one layer at a time, or see what's going on with my code when you feed it a raster stack and make it work for you. If all your layers have the same NA pattern then the index values `ind` will be correct, you then have to extract that index from each layer.